# how to return multiple values from a function and assign it to a array?

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I have a question about Swift.
Here is my code:

```
var theArray = [1, 2, 3]

aFunction(value: 2)

func aFunction(value: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int){
    var value1 = value * 2
    var value2 = value * 4
    var value3 = value * 8

    return theArray[0] = value1
    return theArray[1] = value2
    return theArray[2] = value3
}
```

Is there a way to assign a value that comes from a function and assign it to an Array? What useful patterns exist for assigning function values to *theArray*?

Comment: you need to return a type that supports multiple values:  object, array are two that come to mind.

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. Why do you return tuple from the function? Do you know, that it won't return the actual value of the array but Void? Do you know that you have to return tuple in the function?

Comment: @jnblanchard The edit you suggested is absolutely inappropriate. If you fix the issue in the question itself then there's no more issue and no need to post answers!!! This is ridiculous. Please never do this again. You probably mean well but this is actually vandalism, it's inacceptable.

Comment: I apologize, not my intention. This question as it is posed could use some more clarity and readability. I know I share other's pain when it comes to misinterpreting this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you want your result as an array, why not return an array?

```
func aFunction(value: Int) -> [Int] {
    return [ value * 2, value * 4, value * 8 ]
}

let theArray = aFunction(value: 2)
```

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? The code works. It answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Either your function returns an array or it returns a tuple.  If you return a tuple there is nothing stopping you from wrapping it up in an array once you get the value back:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

var theArray = [1, 2, 3]

func aFunction(value: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int){
  let value1 = value * 2
  let value2 = value * 4
  let value3 = value * 8
  return (value1, value2, value3)
}

var (x,y,z) = aFunction(value: 2)
theArray = [x,y,z]
print(theArray)
```

output:

```
[4, 8, 16]
```

Comment: You should mention that for more variables this method becomes quite painful, since there's no method for converting the tuple to an array automatically, so you'd have to write out each element of the tuple manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the map function:

```
let value = 3
let theArray = [1, 2, 3].map() { $0 * value }
```

You can of course embed this un a func, with theArray and value as parameters

This should answer better to the OP:

```
let value = 2 
var newValue = 1 
var theArray = [1, 2, 3] 
theArray = theArray.map() { (number: Int) -> Int in newValue = newValue * value ; return number * newValue }
```

Comment: What is the `value` property in this case?

Comment: I added the value. But of course, that should be embedded in a func.

Comment: This isn't remotely close to what the code in the question appears to be trying to do. With a `value` of `2`, the answer should be `[4, 8, 16]`. This answer would give `[2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: You should map the iterator.

Comment: I missed a part of the question, sorry.
This should work
let value = 2
var newValue = 1
var theArray = [1, 2, 3]
theArray = theArray.map() { (number: Int) -> Int in newValue = newValue * value ; return number * newValue }

Comment: @claude31 Update your answer. Your answer shouldn't be in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is totally wrong and won't compile, I will provide an answer covering all your aspects:

First of all you need to return Array, not a tuple read the tuple section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

The second thing is you can call `map` function directly in your code so you don't need to create custom function. Check out this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swz9fzL3QB8) - it's beautiful

```
var theArray = [1, 2, 3]

let newArray: [Int] = theArray.enumerated().map { (index, element) in

    switch index {
    case 0:
       return element*2
    case 1:
        return element*4
    case 2:
        return element*8
    default:
        return 0 // You don't really need to do this when you know your Array contains your values. 
    }
}
```

Other useful method could be with iterating over theArray:

```
var theArray = [1, 2, 3]

var newArray: [Int] = []
var iterator = 2
for element in theArray {
    iterator = iterator * 2
    newArray.append(element*iterator)
}
print(newArray)
```

Just wrap these solutions into the function and return the newArray property.

Comment: It could be a misunderstanding in the original question but this solution will return an array of [2, 8, 24] when the original requirement appears to multiply a single value by 2, 4 & 8 to get [4, 8, 16].  However everything else about this is correct so still answers the heart of the question

Comment: Exactly! That's my answer

Answer (score -2):

A good way might be to create your own update block extension on array.

```
  extension Array {
    func normalized(update: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> [Int] {
      var updateArray: [Int] = []
      for (index, element) in self.enumerated() {
        guard let temp = element as? Int else { break }
        updateArray.append(update(index, temp))
      }
      return updateArray
    }
  }
```

Notice that this normalized instance method uses a tuple that includes array position and value.

```
  var theArray = [1,2,3]
```

I declared 'our' function as a map that multiplies entries by 2.

```
  func multiplyMapByTwo(index: Int, value: Int) -> Int {
    let map = [0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 8]
    guard let val = map[index] else { return 0 }
    return 2*val
  }
```

This is the fun part, we now are able to normalize each of theArray's values using the multiply and map function we just created.

```
  theArray = theArray.normalized {
    return multiplyMapByTwo(index: $0, value: $1)
  }

  print(theArray)
```

*theArray* will have **[4, 8, 16]**.

Comment: The expected result is `[4, 8, 16]`. And the question is asking how to return multiple values from a function and assign the result to an array.

Comment: I would have appreciated some clarification rather than a downvote, I think you'll agree, this is better.